# Set a dynamic value for glassfish-embedded-static-shell path

Tags: maven, dependency-injection, dependencies, java-ee-6, pom.xml

In Java EE, I am using:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-static-shell</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${glassfish.embedded-static-shell.jar}</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

in order to test a bean. 
For doing this I need to specify the glassfish.embedded-static-shell.jar location as:

```
 <properties>
    <glassfish.embedded-static-shell.jar>/home/myUser/glassfish\lib\embedded\glassfish-embedded-static-shell.jar</glassfish.embedded-static-shell.jar>
</properties>
```

Is it a way to make the property glassfish.embedded-static-shell.jar dynamic? I tried with glassfish.embedded-static-shell.jar URL, with an env variable, and with a default value and overwriting it maven option "-D" but I can not deploy the project with a dynamic value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24932/embedded-server-guide.htm#gjxff). Assuming your system has the environment variable "S1AS_HOME", you can do the following:

```
<systemPath>
    ${env.S1AS_HOME}/lib/embedded/glassfish-embedded-static-shell.jar
</systemPath>
```

I also admire the fact that you are using an installed Glassfish instance to run your EJBContainer. I consider this to be the best practice as opposed to the "glassfish-embedded-all" artifact which would have to two drawbacks:

1. It lacks the configuration defined in domain.xml
2. If not set up properly it might conflict with the port of an already running Glassfish instance.

Comment: It worked!, before I used an env var also but I think the difference is that I used slash instead of backslash in the path now.